# Android: View Visibility set to View.VISIBLE but View is not Visible

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility

In my app (general construction described below),  I have a timer, which the user can start by clicking an in-app button.
When the timer starts, a notification is shown. In the notification, there's a "STOP" button, which when clicked is supposed to open the app (if closed or killed) and then show a custom dialog.
The custom dialog is built of a bunch of views and a blur-background view.
There are two ways to open that dialog:

1. Clicking an in-app button triggers the method that opens this dialog.
2. Clicking the "STOP" button in the notification also triggers the same method (By calling a `BroadcastReceiver` that lives in the same fragment as the dialog, and in the `BroadcastReceiver` I call the method that opens the dialog - it all happens after the app opens (if it was closed or killed)).

The first method works - clicking the button opens the dialog when it's supposed to.
The second, however, opens the app but not the dialog (To clarify - opening the dialog means changing its views visibility to `View.VISIBLE`).

To check what goes wrong, I used a `Toast` message that shows the visibility of the dialog every time the method that opens the dialog gets called. The `Toast` message shows "`VISIBLE`", so that means the Views visibility is set to `View.VISIBLE` indeed - but the dialog is not shown, nor the blur-background.

***General Construction:*** The app has multiple `Fragments`, stored inside a view pager, inside the `MainActivity` and the dialog lives in the main fragment.

***Might Be Relevant:*** when clicking the notifications button, the app opens, but the notification panel stays fully opened. The `Toast` message shows behind the notification panel.
Also might be worth mentioning, that when I click the notification button while I didn't yet leave the app, the dialog pops up. Only after I leave the app and then come back (manually or by clicking the notification button) the dialog doesn't pop up.

***dialog's XML:*** (stored inside of `fragment_main.xml`)

```
<com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.transformation.FabTransformationSheetBehavior">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15.0dip">

            //Here is the content of the dialog, textviews and custom buttons

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout>
```

***dialog opening method:***

```
private void openDialog() {
    //while "dialog" refers to the "dialog_container" in the dialog xml
    dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fadeBlurIn(); //fades the blur-background view in
    dialog.setClickable(true);
}
```

***calling the method in the `BroadcastReceiver`:*** (stored inside `MainFragment.java`)

```
private final BroadcastReceiver endTimerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            .
            .
            .

            boolean openDialog = {gets a boolean extra, works fine};
            if (openDialog){
                openDialog();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

this `BroadcastReceiver` is attached to this fragment and works fine.

Why doesn't the dialog show?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: none of this really helps, could you please post actual code

Comment: @a_local_nobody There's a lot of code, I think that most of it is irrelevant to the problem, and the problem lies somewhere else because the code works when I open the dialog while I'm in the app clicking the button. I did forget a little thing that also might be relevant, I'll add it right now, but still, it's not a piece code. If there's a specific piece of code you'd want me to share, I'll add it.

Comment: @NitzanDaloomy Have you used: [Live Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to check the state of your dialog? Also how are you testing: device/emulator and OS version.

Comment: @MorrisonChang as I said, I've used Toast messages to know the visibility state of the dialog... and I use a real device to debug the app, a OnePlus 8t, Android 12 OxygenOS 12 (approximately) ROM (the stock one for Oneplus devices)

Comment: @NitzanDaloomy So similar to: [DialogFragment Triggered, but not showing the layout In Navigation Architecture component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63007406/295004)? If not, some code snippets of how your custom dialog is in your main fragment might help. At worst a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Random thought: May be dialog is visible and appearing but it's view is not able to inflate and eventually nothing is displayed on the screen. Also note that, sharing piece of suspicious code or at least implementation where code doesn't work better helps finding the issue.

Comment: @JeelVankhede might be - but how can I find out if that's the problem, and how can I fix it? and I could add some code, but none of it is suspicious to me... the method showing the dialog works flawlessly when triggered from the in-app button. It's called when the notifications button is clicked, and the view's state changes, only not the actual visibility of it... so it might actually be the issue you suggested, the inflation, but how can I make sure the dialog inflates?

Comment: Best way possible is to debug your code using breakpoints from where you initiate a new dialog *(display new dialog)* and then follow your dialog's lifecycle methods that you're using via breakpoints on each lifecycle methods you might have implemented *(I.e. onCreate)*.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'd soon read the thread you suggested, and if you want I could share the code (is the XML the code you seek? or is it the method setting the visibility of the view to visible and the `BroadcastReceiver`(java)?) but anyway I really believe it's not relevant, otherwise I would have shared it... I believe the issue is not with my code, but maybe with my understanding of how android is dealing with visibility state changes or something similar...

Comment: @JeelVankhede I don't create any dialog on runtime... it's created as an XML view, linked to a java `View` Object and then its visibility state is changed by using java's statement `view.setVisibility({visible or invisible state})'... and I've already tried to put breakpoints in the method that changes the visibility state, and debug the app with it, and also there I could see that the state is changed to visible, and still the dialog was not shown

Comment: Try `dialog.invalidate()` after you set visibility and see if it helps

Comment: @JeelVankhede tried that, but it didn't help :/

Comment: Try to give a fixing height and width to the layout

Comment: @ShogunNassar but then the dialog will be too small/big for other devices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem Solved

### What was the issue all about?

The problem was when re-opening the app after closing or leaving it, the main-fragment was re-created, and with it a new blur-background and a new custom dialog.
The `BroadcastReceiver` was stored in the old main-fragment, and so it referred to the old views (the old blur and dialog views)
The old views' visibility has changed, but the new ones didn't, so the visibility state change wasn't visible to the user.

But that's not all. Later on, I discovered that in addition to all that, even if I refer to the right view and try to display it, it's not displaying, and I found another problem - I try to change its visibility state too early.

### Solution

Solving it was quite simple.
All I had to do was make the blur-background and the custom dialog static, so they'll not re-create every time a main-fragment is created. Then Their visibility state changes were visible to the user.

And the solution for the second half of the problem was even easier - all I had to do is put the command calling the method to show the dialog inside a `Runnable`, running in delay by a `Handler`. 10 ms of delay has done the job.

Although this thread's issue is solved by now, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72531946/8099601) issue still isn't.

### Note to self

A good habit is to think ahead, knowing what objects I should set static, so that stuff like this won't happen frequently

Comment: Is it solved? @Nitzan

Comment: @NishaJain Actually, I thought it was, it worked at first, but now it's just better than before, but not completely solved... When clicking the notification-button from outside the app, it opens the app but not the dialog. by clicking the notification-button again, you can open the dialog. In other words, when the app is opened or even re-opened, it works. only when the button is clicked while the app is closed, does it not work.

Answer (score 0):

By notification panel, do you mean it's a bar on top of the app activity?

If so, my guess is that opening the notification panel pushes the dialog outside the device screen. Perhaps the dialog is constrained to the notification panel?

I'm not very sure about this, so sorry if this turns out to be incorrect!

Also, posting some code might help.

Comment: nope, the notification panel is the panel that holds all the notification on any android device, it's a part of the android os

Comment: Oh, I see! Try making the process wait for a while before making the dialog visible, does that work?

Comment: tried that already, it did not :/

Comment: Hmmmmm... not sure so I'll just come up with some suggestions! What about making the dialog as visible _by default_ and then making it invisible **only** if the notification wasn't clicked?

Comment: but it's supposed to be invisible by default, unless the user opens it by using one of the described methods.

Comment: I know, but I think it might be worth a try!

Comment: I'll try that when I can... meanwhile, it's not the ideal solution anyway so I'll keep searching for other solutions (:

Comment: While preparing to try it, I remembered that hiding the dialog means hiding the blur-background, and it's animated, so if I use this way to solve my problem (if it works) the user will see the dialog closing every time this fragment opens, and this is also a problem, so I guess this can't be an option

Answer (score 0):

You have made the view invisible and shown when clicked on either button or notification bar.

You can do is

Make the view visible and add the condition if called by Notification bar it remains as it is, if not then hide it and make it visible again on call on button.

Answer (score 0):

Give the fix height and width to dialog
box and set the visibilty to "Gone".

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

After that call open dialog function and setVisibility to Visible.

Comment: but fixed width and height means the dialog will be too small/big for other devices...

Comment: For this  you can use anything for making the layout responsive. By responsiveness its fit to every screen size. Like in flutter we use mediaquery, screenutil, sizer etc... so you can make your app layout responsive (ConstraintLayout will be workful to you).

Comment: what do you mean? if it fits itself to every screen individually, isn't it in other words `match_parent`?

Comment: I mean if your app is responsive than fix height and width of dialog will not show you small/big for other devices. I will be responsive for all device sizes. So do you app is responsive now? Try to run your app in different devices and check the UI is same or not for all devices.

Comment: match_parent is doesn't mean its responsive. That means the UI view is match to its parent like horizontally and vertically.

Comment: So I lack the understanding of the meaning of responsive... can you explain? do you mean changing it programmatically?

Comment: This is the meaning "Responsive/adaptive layouts provide an optimized user experience regardless of screen size, enabling your app to accommodate phones, tablets, foldable and Chrome OS devices, portrait and landscape orientations, and resizable configurations such as multi-window mode ". I hope now you got what i am saying.

Comment: For now just fix the width and height of the dialog and check its working or not. Will see the responsive later. Your main question is how to show dialog. So very first fix the height and width set both to 250 dp i hope this will work.

Comment: Tried that just now... it doesn't work (I've set the width and height to `250dp`, and visibility to `gone`, but still the dialog doesn't show)

Comment: Please check out my edited question, I've debugged the issue one more time and noticed something new, see under "Might Be Relevant"

Comment: In notifications u have issues or in dialog ? I think the dialog has no issues your notification panel have. Plz debug it correctly and attach some screenshot or video with it

Comment: I'm not sure you understand correctly... The issue is that the dialog does not open when I try to open it using the notifications button unless I click it before leaving the app.

Comment: When you are clicking button inside the app then dialog opens right? Or when you try to open it from notification its didn't work? So might be issue in notification code something like add context to dialog.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase the question so it will be easier to understand the situation. I'll tell you when its updated (:

Comment: Maybe the new edit helps understanding the situation better?