# Collapsing Notification Panel in Android 12

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-12

My app has a notification, that has an action button.
When clicking the button, I want the notification panel (or drawer, you name it) to collapse.
I've found a bunch of solutions, all suggesting the same ([one of them for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420509/8099601)).
This solution doesn't work anymore, at least not for me (on a Oneplus 8t Android 12 device). When that command is called, the app crashes.
What's the updated way to collapse the notification panel?

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui Unfortunately nope... Still waiting for an answer to come, and didn't find any solution anywhere else :(

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui I did find a non-system app that does that. though... While the VPN runs, a notification is displayed in the app 'vpnify'. The notification has a 'disconnect' button, and clicking it opens the app and a dialog while closing the notification panel. So I understand this is actually possible, but I can't manage to understand how can I achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm gonna try more on my side I'll let you know if I figured out how to do that

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an idea after thinking about this question for months. All you need is an empty activity that doesn't show anything. I think this is a little bit hacky, but I don't have better ideas.

**First, create a dummy empty activity that shows nothing, and put the code you would like to do inside that dummy activity.**

DummyActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Do your work here, put the work you would like to do after pressing the button, such as send a broadcast, so your work will still be executed
    //No setContentView() is being called, so nothing will be displayed after opening this activity.
            
    finish();
            
}
```

Remember to add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` for the dummy activity in AndroidManifest.xml so the dummy activity doesn't show in recent apps.

**Second, use** `PendingIntent.getActivity()` **instead, don't use** `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`**, so you should have something like this :**

```
RemoteViews remoteviews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DummyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

remoteviews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MyButton, pendingIntent);
```

With this kind of implementation, after clicking the button, the transparent activity will be started, showing nothing but causing the notification panel to be collapsed.

Comment: I've given it a try, and it works perfectly when the app is not killed, but when I kill it the notification seems to be unable to open an activity while the app is killed... :/ It solves one problem but creates another one instead.